# case statement is setting as model in select merge

Tags: elixir, ecto

These are the params:

```
 %{
  "$select" => %{
    "$avg" => ["arrive_at"],
    "$count" => ["arrive_at"],
    "$fields" => ["id"],
    "$max" => ["cost"],
    "$min" => ["arrive_at"],
    "$sum" => ["arrive_at"]
  }
 }
```

This is the code:

```
 select when is_map(select) ->
        query = from(p in queryable, select: %{})

        fields =
          Enum.reduce(select, [], fn {key, value}, fields ->
            Enum.reduce(value, query, fn {k, v}, query ->
              case k do
                "$avg" ->
                  val = Enum.at(v, 0)

                  query =
                    from(
                      p in query,
                      select_merge: %{avg: avg(field(p, ^String.to_atom(val)))}
                    )

                "$count" ->
                  val = Enum.at(v, 0)

                  query =
                    from(
                      p in query,
                      select_merge: %{count: count(field(p, ^String.to_atom(val)))}
                    )

                "$min" ->
                  val = Enum.at(v, 0)

                  query =
                    from(
                      p in query,
                      select_merge: %{min: min(field(p, ^String.to_atom(val)))}
                    )

                "$max" ->
                  val = Enum.at(v, 0)

                  query =
                    from(
                      p in query,
                      select_merge: %{max: max(field(p, ^String.to_atom(val)))}
                    )

                "$sum" ->
                  val = Enum.at(v, 0)

                  query =
                    from(
                      p in query,
                      select_merge: %{sum: sum(field(p, ^String.to_atom(val)))}
                    )

                "$fields" ->
                  fields = Enum.at(v, 0)
                  IO.inspect(fields)
              end
            end)
           end)
         end
```

If I run this code without the `$fields` statement . It returns the select merge query correctly.

But if I ran it with `$fields`. It gives me the error.

```
  (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Ecto.Queryable not implemented for [:id]
```

Its taking the value of the `$fields` as my model name and using it in query

Why its behaving like that?. Taking the value of the `$fields` as my model.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return anything, that has an `Ecto.Queryable` implementation (namely [`Ecto.Query`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#content),) and your code is currently returning a `List` (`fields`.) Don’t forget **you are inside `reduce`** and the returned value is an accumulator. FWIW,

```
"$fields" ->
  fields = Enum.at(v, 0)
  IO.inspect(fields)
  query   # ⇐ NOTE THE RETURNED VALUE
```

will work as a stub until the proper implementation.